# Float right doesn't float within the box , it floated outside of the box instead

Tags: css, html

I wanted to fixed this box every time at the top of the browser . But there's some problem on the right side I can't figure out how to solve so I asked for helps .

```
#StickyBar #RightSideOfStickyBar
{
    float : right ;
}
```

This should float until the maximum far right side inside the #BoxAlpha . But it is floating until the edge of the browser instead .

I'm also using CSS reset from HTML5 doctor .

Here's HTML5 :

```
    <div id="BoxAlpha">

        <section id="StickyBar">

            <section id="LeftSideOfStickyBar">

                <ul class="Home">
                    <li class="HomeList">
                    <a href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </section>

            <section id="RightSideOfStickyBar">

                <ul class="SignUpAndSignIn">
                    <li class="SignUpAndSignInList">
                    <a href="#">Sign Up</a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="SignUpAndSignInList">
                    <a href="#">Sign In</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </section>

        </section>

    </div>
```

Here's CSS :

```
#BoxAlpha
{
    width : 1000px ; height : auto ; margin-left : auto ; margin-right : auto ;
}

    #StickyBar
    {
        background-color : #EBEBEB ; font-family : "Comic Sans MS" , cursive , sans-serif ; font-size : 1em ; width : 100% ; height : auto ;
        line-height : 50px ; background : linear-gradient( #00FFFF , #4D70DB ) ; border-style : solid ; border-color : #999999 ;
        position : fixed ; top : 0 ; z-index : 1 ;
    }


        #StickyBar #LeftSideOfStickyBar
        {
            float : left ;
        }

            #StickyBar #LeftSideOfStickyBar .Home
            {
                list-style : none ;
            }

            #StickyBar #LeftSideOfStickyBar .Home .HomeList
            {
                float : left ; width : 7em ; text-align : center ;
            }

            #StickyBar #LeftSideOfStickyBar .Home .HomeList > a
            {
                font-weight : 550 ; text-decoration : none ; color : #000000 ; cursor : default ;
            }

        #StickyBar #RightSideOfStickyBar
        {
            float : right ;
        }

            #StickyBar #RightSideOfStickyBar .SignUpAndSignIn
            {
                list-style : none ;
            }

            #StickyBar #RightSideOfStickyBar .SignUpAndSignIn .SignUpAndSignInList
            {
                float : left ; width : 7em ; text-align : center ;
            }

            #StickyBar #RightSideOfStickyBar .SignUpAndSignIn .SignUpAndSignInList > a
            {
                font-weight : 550 ; text-decoration : none ; color : #000000 ; cursor : default ;
            }
```

Comment: Try giving clearfix class to your parent section #StickyBar. Share a fiddle link of your work

Comment: You're not floating anything right... What is the problem?

Comment: @karan3112 Sorry I didn't get you do you mind to say again ? What's a "fiddle" ? I'm sorry I'm still new in web developing

Comment: I did float something on the right but it is not floating correctly

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ Put your code on this and and share its link which will help us resolve your problem.

Comment: It seems to float fine [in this example](http://jsbin.com/setawo/1/edit). Also, [comic sans is blasphemy!](http://www.comicsanscriminal.com/)

Comment: It seems to be floating as expected; except may be `#StickyBar` is contained inside a narrow div; from which it inherits 100% width which would also be narrow. I suggest that you replace `width: 100%` with `left: 0; right: 0;`.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/setawo/1    it looks something like this at my desktop , only if when I maximize my chrome it looks something like this . the #stickybar 100% width should be = 1000px , but the float right at RightSideOfStickyBar goes out to the browser .

Comment: This is after with CSS reset .. http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=vtBxUn5VJG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so your code could be simplified a little. But to start with... because the header is `position: fixed`, it is not confined by it's container; it will position itself like it is the only element on your page.

From [CSS absolute and fixed positioning](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_absolute_and_fixed_positioning) on w3.org:

> Fixed positioning is really just a specialized form of absolute positioning; **elements with fixed positioning are fixed relative to the viewport/browser window rather than the containing element**; even if the page is scrolled, they stay in exactly the same position inside the browser window.

If you want to keep `position: fixed`, the solution is to give it a `max-width`:

CSS

```
#StickyBar {
max-width: 1000px;
}
```

[Here is an example.](http://jsbin.com/setawo/2/edit)

OR, if you don't want `position: fixed`, remove it and add `overflow:hidden` like so:

CSS

```
#StickyBar {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

It will now adhere to the width of its parent.

[Here is an example without position:fixed](http://jsbin.com/setawo/6/edit)

---

If you are interested, I have also created a simple layout that you could work with.

[Have a new layout example!](http://jsbin.com/yohik/1/edit)

HTML

```
<header>
    <nav class="pages">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
    </nav>
    <nav class="signin">
        <a href="#">Signup</a>
        <a href="#">Signin</a>
    </nav>
</header>
```

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,body {
    height: 100%;
    font: 100% Helvetica;
}

header { 
    max-width: 1000px;
    height: 80px;
    background:linear-gradient(#0FF,#4D70DB);
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

header nav { 
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

header .signin {
    text-align: right;
}

a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: This is after with CSS reset .. jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=vtBxUn5VJG .. if I fixed the position of #StickyBar (top 0 ) shouldn't it be fixed inside the div ? Why do you meant by "not confined by it's container that has a width" I don't understand .

Comment: A `position: fixed` element will always remain fixed to the viewport (the viewable area of the browser window). It will ignore its parent elements when positioning.

Comment: I have added a simplified example of your layout in my answer, without `position: fixed` for the moment :)

Comment: By "not confined by its container", I mean that it will ignore all the other elements around it when it gets positioned. It will look the same as if it was the only bit of code on your page.

Comment: wait a second i'm still digesting ... i'm sorry i'm noob ... slowly lol thanks by the way

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bluesever_v3_dota/dojgkbxq/1/     http://jsfiddle.net/bluesever_v3_dota/dojgkbxq/1/embedded/result/   I used max-width : 100% and 1000px which you suggested but still doesn't work . The Right and Left side of the sticky bar got combine together into a smaller width like floating side by side which one and another . If I change max-width back to width : 100% , and remove position : fixed , top : 0 , z-index : 1 , it will be exactly what I want to look like but it doesn't stick on the top .